Parallel Tasks - Run Parallel threads but dont wait for other Tasks to complete and get the latest data from database
I am using Task library for running multiple tasks parallelly, and I am using below code to wait for other tasks to complete.
Parallel.ForEach(DatafromDB,
  item => { DownloadSSR(mediator, sourcePath, item,stoppingToken).Wait();
});

Using this I felt like I am not really doing parallelly, because say for Eg:  3 tasks, Task1, Task2 and Task3.
Task1 say takes 15 mins, and other tasks take 1 min respectively, in this case we are waiting for all the Tasks to complete.
To Achieve this I got one more option to use - "MaxDegreeOfParallelism"
Parallel.ForEach(DatafromDB,
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3}, 
  item => { DownloadSSR(mediator, sourcePath, item,stoppingToken).Wait();
});

Now tasks are running parallelly but its taking the data from DB only for the first time.
Eg: if there are 3 data i got from DB then same data source is being used for running tasks parallely.
Here what i want to achieve is -

I want to run the tasks parallelly.
I don't need to wait for other tasks to complete
If one task completed, assign other work to that task (go to Database and get data and assign new work)


"I don't need to wait for other tasks to complete" -- This is called fire-and-forget, and it is generally inadvisable. Are you sure about that?

This question might be related: Task.WhenAny with cancellation of the non completed tasks and timeout.

I got what you meant, but what i was thinking is - we should have the control on the tasks (not fire and forget) but it should not have to wait for other tasks in the list, say one task in taking very long time then my all threads will take more time to complete.

One more way i was thinking, to have batch of tasks for which it will take time and other batch for tasks which dont take much time,  need you views on this too

If a task in taking very long time, it means that either your hardware or some other connected hardware is struggling to complete the task. By firing-and-forgetting the task you make it trivial to start a new long-running operation while the previous one is still running, overloading the system even more. Not only your users, but also the other systems' administrators are going to hate your software.

Understood,  its taking long time because it has to get the data from multiple systems (Around 5) which are all vendor side apps, so no much we can do there,  so the option i thought is, to run long running ones in different list of tasks. Let me know if this makes sense.

Can you pass a CancellationToken when you call these vendor side apps? If not, are you sure that these vendor side apps will be happy if you call each one of them concurrently (because you fired-and-forget the previous calls)?

Can you explain in more details what you mean by "If one task completed, assign other work to that task"

Sure @Magnus.  Say for Eg: Task1, Task2, Task 3 there,  Task1 is completed in short time (say 1 min) , Task 2 and Task 3 may be taking long (say15 mins), since Task 1 is done with processing, i need to go to DB and get the pending requests to process to assign to Task1

I dont see that you are doing that in the current code. Can you add that so I can understand what you mean.

What does DownloadSSR actually do? If, as the name suggests, executes HTTP calls you should use ParallelForEachAsync. Downloading is IO-bound. Using Parallel.ForEach would only block all CPU cores while waiting for a response from the remote server. It seems you really need await Parallel.ForEachAsync(data,(item,ct)=>DownloadSSR(mediator, sourcePath, item,ct));

There are a lot of questions asking how to make multiple concurrent HTTP calls and a lot of good answers that show how to do that properly. You can use Parallel.ForEachAsync, you can use Dataflow blocks.

@PanagiotisKanavos yes you are right. It will get the data from multiple systems (around 5) and create a report and download. all the calls between the system is http rest calls.

So once a DownloadSSR Task is compelted you want to cancel the other ongoing and continue with that one?

Have you tried await Parallel.ForEachAsync(data,(item,ct)=>DownloadSSR(mediator, sourcePath, item,ct)); ? ForEachAsync understands tasks and will await all of the pending tasks to complete before returning. By default it will start as many concurrent tasks as there are cores, but you can increase or decrease that if you need. Parallel.ForEach doesn't understand tasks so what you wrote is equivalent to calling an async void method. It can't be awaited.

@Magnus  No i dont want to cancel,  as i said above,  If there are 3 tasks,  Task 1 completes in short time,  Task 2 and Task 3 taking long time, then i dont want to cancel anything,  Task 2 and Task 3 let it take its own sweet time to give the response, for Task 1 once completed, i want to assign the other report download work

Thanks for all the responses.
Actually I wanted fire and forget mechanism for my requirement, and i know it will put some load on my server, but its fine for me as i am limiting number of threads to be 3 (using maximum degree of parallelism) and i thought Hangfire is one of the best for this requirement.

This will execute the tasks in parallel and give you the result as they complete.
var tasks = DatafromDB.Select(item => DownloadSSR(mediator, sourcePath, item, stoppingToken)).ToList();
await foreach (var result in ProcessTasksInOrder(tasks))
{
    await DoStuff(result);
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ProcessTasksInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var tasksToProcess = tasks.ToList();

    while (tasksToProcess.Count > 0)
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasksToProcess);
        yield return completedTask.Result;
        tasksToProcess.Remove(completedTask);
    }
}


Thanks @Magnus.  If  Task 1 completed, again i need to call Db and assign the updated list to "DatafromDB"  and as per the code here, Task 2 and Task 3 will not give the downloaded report as its taking more time ?

I've changed it so that you will get the tasks in order as they complete.
